# Creating an IF condition in JavaScript based on hexadecimal colors

Tags: javascript, html

I have a line of JavaScript that allows me to make the background of my webpage a different colour each time the page is loaded:

```
document.getElementById("band").style.background = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
```

For visibility, I want to have the font be either black or white, depending on whether the background is dark or light.

For example, I think the "halfway" point in hexadecimal is #800000.

I want my script to tell my webpage to use white font if the hexadecimal number is less than 800000 and use black font if the hexadecimal number is more than 800000.

Comment: RGB is the worst colour model to do that. You'll possibly need to convert to HSL.

Comment: You can't treat RGB values like actual hex numbers. Compare `0x7fffff` to `0x800001`, for example.

Comment: Ah I see. So should I use the script I have in my question and THEN convert to HSL and THEN put the IF condition in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TinyColor](https://bgrins.github.io/TinyColor/) library

```js
var color = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);

document.write("<b style=\"color:" + color + ";\">" + color + "<\/b> is ");

var c = tinycolor(color);

if (c.isDark()) 
  document.write("Dark");
else 
  document.write("Light");
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/bgrins/TinyColor/master/tinycolor.js"></script>
```